# how to print a value after a specific string

Tags: c, string

I am trying to read in a file, find the string "myprop" and after "myprop" will be an "=" sign then a number. I need to print out just that number as a string, getting rid of blank spaces and comments. I am able to locate the "myprop" string and then I believe I should be using fscanf but I am having trouble with that.

```
const char *get_filename_property()
{
    const char *filename  = "myfile.properties";
    const char *propkey = "myprop";
    char buffer[100], *buffPtr, lastChar, value[50];
    int line_num=1, i=0;

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("myfile.properties", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        perror("Error opening file\n\n");

    while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if((strstr(buffer, propkey)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("Myprop found on line: %d\n", line_num);
            printf("\n%s\n", buffer);
        }
        line_num++;
    }
    if (fp)
        fclose(fp);
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    get_filename_property();
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What if some part of `propkey` located at first loaded buffer and rest of it located at second loaded buffer? You can not find `propkey` in the file in this situation.

Comment: Do you need to actually use the value at any point in your program, or are you just printing it out? If all you need to do is print it, I wouldn't bother converting it - just find the `=` sign (use the return value of `strstr()` and the known length of `"myprop"` to calculate where to start scanning) and directly copy characters following that to output until you hit an end of line or space or another character that isn't part of the value. If you need the value, rather than `sscanf()`, locate the start of the value and use the appropriate `strto?()` functions to convert.

Comment: You may want to consider returning something from `get_filename_property()` besides whatever random value is sitting in the primary CPU register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `sscanf` in the moment when you find the `mypop` string in the file. Add the following line in your while loop:

```
sscanf(buf,"%*[^=]= %[^\n]",value);
```

`"%*[^=]"`: This means that scanf capte all characters befor the `=` and ignore it

`" %[^\n]"`: This means that you are capting all characters after the `=` till the end of your buffer string (even the space characters). only the space characters in the beggining of the value string will not capted

add it in this way

```
while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
 {
  if((strstr(buffer, propkey)) != NULL)
  {
   printf("Myprop found on line: %d\n", line_num);
   printf("\n%s\n", buffer);
   sscanf(buf,"%*[^=]= %[^\n]",value);
   printf("\nvalue is %s\n", value);
   break;
  }
  line_num++;
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your example code pass `buffer` into the call to `sscanf`?

Comment: awesome this works, thank you. One more question though, how can I not print comments? if the line where propkey is located said myprop = 1  //value, how could I get rid of the backslashes and everything after that

Comment: @user1984300 All of your values are integers ?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL the output of printf("\nvalue is %s\n", value) is: value is 1   //value.

Comment: if they are `double` then use `sscanf(buf,"%*[^=]= %f",&value);` and value should be defined as double: `double value;`  With that you will avoid the capture of any string after your double. And do not forget to change also the printf to `printf("\nvalue is %f\n", value);`

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL okay thanks again, one more thing(the details of my assignment werent very specific). What if instead of a number after the = sign there is a few strings seperated by spaces? example: myprop=this is a sentence //value