# Printing multiple strings with printf in C

Tags: c, string, printf, scanf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to print a value after a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362869/how-to-print-a-value-after-a-specific-string)

So for my original assignment I had to print a single character after the string "myprop=" but not I was told I need to print a few strings after the = sign without printing the comments.

An example would be: myprop=this is a sentence //value. Basically I need to modify the sscanf and printf functions.

```
const char *get_filename_property()
{
  const char *filename  = "myfile.properties";
  const char *propkey = "myprop=";
  char buffer[1024], *buffPtr, lastChar, value[50];
  int line_num=1;
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("myfile.properties", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {  
    perror("Error opening file\n\n");
    return -1;
  } 

  while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp) != NULL)
  {
    if((strstr(buffer, propkey)) != NULL)
    {  
      printf("\nmyprop= found on line %d\n", line_num);
      sscanf(buffer,"%*[^=]=%s",value); 
      printf("\nvalue is %s\n", value);
    }
    line_num++;
  } 

  if(fp)
  { 
    fclose(fp); //close the file if it is still open
  }

  return 0;
}      

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{  
  get_filename_property();
  system("pause");
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: same code but a different task

Comment: `if(fp)
  { 
   fclose(fp); //close the file if it is still open
  }` The function would already have returned if fp were null. BTW: what is a comment? please show us the file format and explain your goals.

Comment: so if the line where myprop was located said: myprop=this is a sentence //value, the //value is the comment. the file format would have text above and below the line with myprop.

Comment: nevermind I figured it out, this is now my sscanf function: sscanf(buffer,"%*[^=]= %[^\\\n]",value);